# Error with .eps file

Tags: eps

I am using texstudio editor, everything is ok while using this. But suddenly I found error as shown below
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `../temperature-zero/drag-SLG-D-t/figure/rho-log-T-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.**strong text**

I have also replace Miktex by texlive but problem is same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error message says what's wrong. It cannot find that file or cannot convert it. Did it ever work with the eps file? Does the converted pdf exist? Can you run epstopdf on the eps file on the command line? Can you show us the relevant part of the .log file, and of the code?